# How to set users rights with Windows Authentication with asp.net core

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core

Please provide guidance on how to set users which may operate in application with Windows Authentication on ASP.NET Core

In Asp.Net MVC 5 I do it with web.config:

```
<authorization>
      <allow users="domain\foo, domain\bar, domain\baz/>
      <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

How implement this with asp.net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a global authorization policy:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .RequireAssertion(x =>
                         x.User.Identity.Name == "domain\\foo" ||
                         x.User.Identity.Name == "domain\\bar" ||
                         x.User.Identity.Name == "domain\\baz")
                   .Build();
   config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But it hardcoded. Is it possible to make it with project.json or web.config?

Comment: My example is just for illustration, you could store user names in `appsettings.json` or another store. Then you can check if user store contains current user name. Take a look at Configuration docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: I'm getting the following error even with  "services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);"  Could you help me with solve this?: InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).